# Fatal Error on website

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I had to upgrade our website Open Cart from 1.5.5.1 to 2.0.1.1 because our hosting company decided to upgrade the PHP. Now the website does not work anymore and gives a fatal error. I don't understand anything from this fatal error code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'error_theme_option_file_lost' in /public/sites/www.hippehangmatten.nl/catalog/model/kuler/cp.php:40
>   Stack trace:
>    #0 /public/sites/www.hippehangmatten.nl/system/modification/catalog/controller/module/kuler_cp.php(2157): ModelKulerCp->loadThemeOptions(NULL)
>    #1 /public/sites/www.hippehangmatten.nl/system/modification/catalog/controller/module/kuler_cp.php(2966): Kuler->processStyles()
>    #2 /public/sites/www.hippehangmatten.nl/system/modification/system/library/response.php(63): Kuler->processOutput('...')
>    #3 /public/sites/www.hippehangmatten.nl/index.php(266): Response->output()
>    #4 {main} thrown in /public/sites/www.hippehangmatten.nl/catalog/model/kuler/cp.php on line 40

I hope that somebody can help me to fix this problem. The designer of this theme ended their company, so I am not able to reach out to them.

Comment: Well, from the error message it looks like some file could not be opened. Unfortunately, this file `kuler/cp.php` seems like it is closed source, so you would have to show its contents somewhere for someone to help you.

Comment: Tnx for you response. I have more than one websites and copied the other onem because that one is working properly with this theme and OpenCart version. Then I change the database information and get this fatal error. Is it possible that the problem does nog lie with the kuler/cp.php, but with the database?

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible, but impossible to decide without being able to look into the code throwing the error. But judging from what I see in the stacktrace nothing hints that it's indeed a database problem.